# No module called cv2

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu, anaconda

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I follow the official install instruction of OpenCV.
When I tried to import `cv2` on python3.8, it shows

```
No module named cv2
```

but for python2.7, it works for me and I use the command `cmake ../` to access and it only shows python2.7 has built into it. Does anyone meet the same problem? Please see the screenshot for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installed python package opencv-python using pip?

Try this

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Comment: Have you build and then make opencv in your system?

Comment: follow this https://dev.to/swervin/how-to-install-opencv-4-2-0-on-ubuntu-18-04-3i7l

Answer (score 0):

Open the containing folder of your `python.exe` of Python 2.7, and there you will find the `site-packages` folder. In there, copy the cv2 folder, and paste it into the Python 3.8 `site-packages` folder.

Comment: Hi Ann,  my cv2 folder was already inside the python3.8 site-package folder.